# Input and Data Validator for Python not working

Tags: python

I'm working on a program that's going to calculate flight times but I just can't seem to figure this out. I'm essentially displaying the potential airports to choose from. If the user inputs something that is not accurate, I want the question to loop until it's correct. Otherwise the program should proceed. However, it's not working:

```
airports = {
  "New York": {'JFK', "LGA"},
  "California": {"LAX", "LGB"}
}

def list_airports(city):
  if origin == city:
    print(airports[city])
  elif destination == city:
   print(airports[city])

def data_validator(var1, var2):
  if var1 not in var2:
    print("Uh oh! That's not valid. Please be mindful that the program is case sensitive.")
    input("Try again: ")

origin = input("What state are you flying from? Type the number from the list: ")
data_validator(origin, airports)

l.append(origin)
list_airports(origin)

airport1 = input("Ok! Which ariport are you flying from the list above? Type the three letter airport code: ")
data_validator(airport1, list_airports) 

destination = input("What state are you going to?: ")
list_airports(destination)
airport2 = input("Ok! Which ariport from the list above? Type the three letter acronym for the airport: ")
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    data_validator(airport1, list_airports) 
  File "main.py", line 13, in data_validator
    if var1 not in var2:
TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
```

Comment: what does list_airports do here, Add your complete code.

Comment: when the user first enters which state, new york for example, list_airports will then list the three letter codes for the airports in the state

Comment: Its not sufficient, list_airports is culprit here.

Comment: Well, `list_airports` is a function. What do you expect `data_validator(airport1, list_airports) ` to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do with list_airports? it is not defined in your peace of code! list_airport seem to be a function, so the error is normal

Comment: @PascalFares `list_airports` is defined. As you said yourself, it is a function...

Answer (score 0):

list_airports is a function, not a value that can be assessed.  You want your data_validator to be:

```
data_validator(airport1, airports[origin])
```

That should assess the user input against your airport codes for that state.